# Code works in postman but not in the script - 47-Maximum (20) redirects followed

Tags: php, curl, postman

I created and tested one post request on postman and it gives me back correct page, but when I put this code inside my PHP it doesn't work, I 've got error:

`47-Maximum (10) redirects followed`

```
  $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://xxxxx.com/login/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"email=xxxx.xxxx%40mail.com&password=xxxxu&url=",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type:  application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Any help?

Comment: Perhaps because your url parameter in form data is empty? Just a guess.

Comment: its not that....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using self signed certificate you should disable ssl check with curl.

`curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are using browser user-agent, you need to enable cookies too.
Set options for cookie file, as follows:

```php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://xxxxx.com/login/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"email=xxxx.xxxx%40mail.com&password=xxxxu&url=",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type:  application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36"
  ),
  // ****** Add following options ******
  CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => dirname(__FILE__). '/cookies.txt',
  CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => dirname(__FILE__). '/cookies.txt',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```